# How to apply a color gradient to a shapefile from QGIS console?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Anyone knows how to do a color gradient from the console to a shapefile in QGIS (or in Python)? Like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible in QGIS 2.0. (We already had this question in 2011 - just without the Python aspect: [Polygon gradient fills / tint bands in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13233/polygon-gradient-fills-tint-bands-in-qgis?rq=1))

For the next version, a gradient fill has been announced by http://nyalldawson.net/2013/09/sneak-peak/:

[image]

This is the responsible class: http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsGradientFillSymbolLayerV2.html
and there seems to be an option to let the gradient start from the center of the polygon:

> ```
> setReferencePoint1IsCentroid (bool isCentroid)
> ```
>
> Sets the starting point of the gradient to be the feature centroid

Comment: I'm trying to Keep the Control of gradient mathematically. Thing I see that is not possible.

Comment: @Vassilis then I suggest to get on the bug tracker and discuss it as a new feature request.